# Android ListView array index out of bounds after filter

Tags: android, listview, filter, android-arrayadapter

I think this is a question for experts.

I get calls to `getView()` with *positon* **out of bounds** from the *ListView* data list.
This happens when I use the Adapter filter. The filter `publishResults()` method populates the data with a filtered list which is smaller than the original list.
The error seems to occur when the new filtered list **is shorter than the previous**  filtered list.
I changed the code of `getView()` to return a dummy *convertView* when out of bounds, just to see how many such calls are issued.

These are the relevant code and the `log` messages I logged:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // No logs here to keep ListView performance good
        Log.d(TAG, "+ getView( position=" + position + ")");
        ViewHolder holder;

        if( position >= mData.size() ) {
            // This code allows to see how many bad calls I get
            Log.w(TAG, "position out of bounds!");
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(mLayout, parent, false);
            return convertView;
        }

        . . . // Normal getView code

        return convertView;
    }
```

In the filter (code copied as is from `ArrayAdapter` source code)

```
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            Log.pe(TAG, "+ publishResults(constraint:" + constraint + ", results.count:" + results.count + ")");
            //noinspection unchecked
            mData = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;
            if (results.count > 0) {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
            Log.px(TAG, "- publishResults()");
        }
```

The log file shows that after a filter with 7 results, comes a fitler with 3 results, but `getView` keeps getting calls for 7 items (I marked with `***` the out of bounds calls):

```
02-26 05:31:55.986: D/ViewerActivity(22857): + onQueryTextChange(newText:log)
02-26 05:31:55.986: D/ViewerActivity(22857): - onQueryTextChange()
02-26 05:31:56.029: D/LogScreenAdapter(22857): + performFiltering(prefix:log)
02-26 05:31:56.113: D/dalvikvm(22857): GC_CONCURRENT freed 378K, 5% free 13577K/14215K, paused 0ms+1ms
02-26 05:31:56.153: D/LogScreenAdapter(22857): - performFiltering()
02-26 05:31:56.153: D/LogScreenAdapter(22857): + publishResults(constraint:log, results.count:7)
02-26 05:31:56.167: D/LogScreenAdapter(22857): - publishResults()
02-26 05:31:56.167: D/LogScreenAdapter(22857): + getView( position=0)
02-26 05:31:56.167: D/LogScreenAdapter(22857): + getView( position=0)
02-26 05:31:56.167: D/LogScreenAdapter(22857): + getView( position=0)
02-26 05:31:56.167: D/LogScreenAdapter(22857): + getView( position=1)
02-26 05:31:56.167: D/LogScreenAdapter(22857): + getView( position=2)
02-26 05:31:56.167: D/LogScreenAdapter(22857): + getView( position=3)
02-26 05:31:56.167: D/LogScreenAdapter(22857): + getView( position=4)
02-26 05:31:56.167: D/LogScreenAdapter(22857): + getView( position=5)
02-26 05:31:56.167: D/LogScreenAdapter(22857): + getView( position=6)
02-26 05:31:56.167: D/LogScreenAdapter(22857): + getView( position=0)
02-26 05:31:56.167: D/LogScreenAdapter(22857): + getView( position=1)
02-26 05:31:56.167: D/LogScreenAdapter(22857): + getView( position=2)
02-26 05:31:56.167: D/LogScreenAdapter(22857): + getView( position=3)
02-26 05:31:56.167: D/LogScreenAdapter(22857): + getView( position=4)
02-26 05:31:56.493: D/LogScreenAdapter(22857): + getView( position=5)
02-26 05:31:56.503: D/LogScreenAdapter(22857): + getView( position=6)
02-26 05:32:23.793: D/ViewerActivity(22857): + onQueryTextChange(newText:logs)
02-26 05:32:23.793: D/ViewerActivity(22857): - onQueryTextChange()
02-26 05:32:23.813: D/LogScreenAdapter(22857): + performFiltering(prefix:logs)
02-26 05:32:23.854: D/dalvikvm(22857): GC_CONCURRENT freed 383K, 5% free 13577K/14215K, paused 0ms+0ms
02-26 05:32:23.924: D/dalvikvm(22857): GC_CONCURRENT freed 388K, 5% free 13573K/14215K, paused 0ms+1ms
02-26 05:32:23.974: D/LogScreenAdapter(22857): - performFiltering()
02-26 05:32:23.983: D/LogScreenAdapter(22857): + publishResults(constraint:logs, results.count:3)
02-26 05:32:23.983: D/LogScreenAdapter(22857): - publishResults()
02-26 05:32:23.983: D/LogScreenAdapter(22857): + getView( position=0)
02-26 05:32:24.074: D/LogScreenAdapter(22857): + getView( position=0)
02-26 05:32:24.093: D/LogScreenAdapter(22857): + getView( position=0)
02-26 05:32:24.113: D/LogScreenAdapter(22857): + getView( position=1)
02-26 05:32:24.155: D/LogScreenAdapter(22857): + getView( position=2)
02-26 05:32:24.164: D/LogScreenAdapter(22857): + getView( position=3)
*** 02-26 05:32:24.193: W/LogScreenAdapter(22857): position out of bounds!
02-26 05:32:24.233: D/LogScreenAdapter(22857): + getView( position=4)
*** 02-26 05:32:24.263: W/LogScreenAdapter(22857): position out of bounds!
02-26 05:32:24.284: D/LogScreenAdapter(22857): + getView( position=5)
*** 02-26 05:32:24.313: W/LogScreenAdapter(22857): position out of bounds!
02-26 05:32:24.333: D/LogScreenAdapter(22857): + getView( position=6)
*** 02-26 05:32:24.343: W/LogScreenAdapter(22857): position out of bounds!
02-26 05:32:24.353: D/LogScreenAdapter(22857): + getView( position=0)
02-26 05:32:24.373: D/LogScreenAdapter(22857): + getView( position=1)
02-26 05:32:24.383: D/LogScreenAdapter(22857): + getView( position=2)
02-26 05:32:24.403: D/LogScreenAdapter(22857): + getView( position=3)
*** 02-26 05:32:24.413: W/LogScreenAdapter(22857): position out of bounds!
02-26 05:32:24.433: D/LogScreenAdapter(22857): + getView( position=4)
*** 02-26 05:32:24.443: W/LogScreenAdapter(22857): position out of bounds!
02-26 05:32:24.463: D/LogScreenAdapter(22857): + getView( position=5)
*** 02-26 05:32:24.475: W/LogScreenAdapter(22857): position out of bounds!
02-26 05:32:24.483: D/LogScreenAdapter(22857): + getView( position=6)
*** 02-26 05:32:24.503: W/LogScreenAdapter(22857): position out of bounds!
02-26 05:38:26.769: D/dalvikvm(22857): GC_CONCURRENT freed 316K, 5% free 13640K/14215K, paused 0ms+1ms
```

What you are seeing here, the `publishResults()` method did change mData from a list of 7 items to a shorter list of 3 items, see the code above, but the `Adapter` keeps getting `getView()` calls for the 7 items list, even that it is not longer there.
Note that `notifyDataSetChanged()` has been called with the new data assignment, so the `ListView` should be aware of the new list.

Comment: Is the getItemCount function being called, and if so what is it returning?  Ir you're overriding it, post the code.

Comment: What does getItemCount return?

Comment: I don't override getItemCount, should I?

Comment: I think this is a question for experts. HILARIOUS!

Comment: @RobinHood That only means I am not an expert. Glad I could make you smile. I changed the code an so far I did not get anymore out of bounds. If anyone would care to post the answer I will mark it as answered.

Comment: @ilomambo, +1 for asking this question. Maybe a noobie question to some, but I had the same problem and the answers solved it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

what are you returning in `public int getCount()` method of custom list view adapter?

You should return like `mData != null? mData.size() : 0`,

Position out of bond is getting due to may be you are returning size of list more than data to show in the list

`getCount()` method of custom list adapter specifies size of list view so it should be the size of data you are passing in the list

Comment: you saved my day! I totally forgot to override the `getCount`method

Answer (score 21):

Seems like overriding of "getCount()" method will solve your problem:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mData.size();
}
```

Comment: this statement exists but same issue

Answer (score 0):

I did this and it solved my problems

```
@Override
public int getCount() {

    if (isFiltered == true) {
        return myFilteredArray.size();
    }

    return myUnfilteredArray.size();
}
```