# notifyDataSetChanged() crash while fast scroll

Tags: android, listview, notifydatasetchanged

**Situation:**

I'm update data on `ListView` by calling `notifyDataSetChanged` 4~10 seconds a time.

It works well when I scroll it slowly. however as I scroll it a little bit fast, the application crashes.

```
E/InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event.
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.timeleap.timtor.DophWifi, PID: 22014
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
at com.timeleap.timtor.DophWifi.DolphinAdapter.getView(DolphinAdapter.java:99)
```

**What I Thought:**

When scrolling listview, application will call getview for about-to-visible items of the listview. Once `notifyDataSetChanged` called when you are scrolling, it will mess up and crash.

**Temporary Solution:**

I try to bybass this somehow seems a "bug" in some Adapter [[1]](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/3fbuno/is_this_a_common_recyclerview_bug/). Just simply add this code before you getting data by position.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    //checking convertView is null or not

    if(data.size()> position && data.size()!=0) {
        holder.text1.setText(data.get(position));
        //other holders...
    }
}
```

After adding this code, the listview seems never crash because 
(Even I crazily scroll the listview :P)

**Problems:**

Is there any other better method to avoid crash ? It seems a strange but common problem...

Comment: how you are updating data. are you removing all items also or only adding items ?

Comment: Please follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15105004/android-listview-array-index-out-of-bounds-after-filter

Comment: I guess this has to do with the way your adapter is getting the data that it is using to populate the view.

Comment: I use `data.clear()`  and `data.add()` in background, and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`  in `onPostExecute` method.

Comment: Oh... I didn't find that post  before asking question. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15105235/5558764) do help fix problem of null data, but in case of getting data out of bound I suggest using the code above to bypass it.